# List view to open in different browser . . 

Tags: 2007

We have a listview webpart with links list . When the links are clicked,  it opens in the same browser, but the requirement is to open the links in a new window when the user clicks on the link. If anyone has worked on a similar requirement please guide us on this.

Answer (score 1):

One idea - have you considered just using the "Preview Pane" view type? Like you can set when you "Modify this view"? It shows you a list of your list items, and a preview pane to show their details - would that fulfill your actual requirement, or do you really need another window opened?

Failing that, you could use SharePoint Designer to convert your ListView web part into a DataView web part. Then you can just edit how the link field targets it's links - you need to find the

`<a href="..."`

bit and add an attribute of:

```
target="_blank"
```

Otherwise, I think I'd start by trying to use jQuery to select the links in my listview and make then target a new browser - which has [just been posted on nothingbutsharepoint.com](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Invoke-New-Window-with-Unique-URL-Keyword.aspx)